# sum the values of all occurrences parameters

Tags: awk, numeric-data

we have the following file ,

in file we can see the same parameters names with their values

```
more file.txt

gg_ff_rr =56
gg_ff_rr =56
gg_ff_rr =52
jk_ll_tt=24
jk_ll_tt=24
jk_ll_tt=24
pl_pl_uu=10
pl_pl_uu=8
pl_pl_uu=10
ww_ee_qq=2
ww_ee_qq=2
ww_ee_qq=1
oo_pp_ww=10
oo_pp_ww=10
mm_mm_bb=1
AA_AA_AA=1
AA_AA_AA=1
AA_AA_AA=1
AA_AA_AA=1
.
.
.
.
```

We plan to sum the values of all the occurrences parameters so the expected output will be like this

```
gg_ff_rr=164
jk_ll_tt=72
pl_pl_uu=28
ww_ee_qq==5
oo_pp_ww=20
mm_mm_bb=1
AA_AA_AA=4
.
.
.
.
```

how can it be done with bash/awk/shell-script or Perl one liner

**we try the following**

```
awk -F= '{a[$1]+=$2;}END{for(i in a){print i "=" a[i]}}'  /tmp/file.txt

macafi___pp___export___weer 100=0
macafi___pp___my_name___gtp___state 100=0
macafi___pp___my_name___gtp___enr 100=0
macafi___pp___trw___initial___mixed 100=0
macafi___pp___my_name___broad 100=0
macafi___pp___adc___voip___stat 100=0
macafi___pp___my_name___gtp 300=0
macafi___pp___trw___initial 200=0
```

**while the file is like this**

```
more /tmp/file.txt

macafi___pp___my_name___broad 100
macafi___pp___my_name___gtp 300
macafi___pp___my_name___gtp___enr 100
macafi___pp___my_name___gtp___state 100
macafi___pp___adc___voip___stat 100
macafi___pp___export___weer 100
macafi___pp___trw___initial 200
macafi___pp___trw___initial___mixed 100
macafi___pp___trw___initial___mixed 100
macafi___pp___trw___initial___mixed 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way(if order of output is not an issue):

```
awk -F= '{a[$1]+=$2;}END{for(i in a){print i "=" a[i]}}' file
```

Read the file into an array with 1st column as index, and the value getting added with the 2nd col value. Once the file is parsed, just print the entries of the array.

Updated(since the new file has space as delimiter):

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2;}END{for(i in a){print i " " a[i]}}' file
```

Comment: @Isaac . sorry, my bad.. thanks for pointing it out.. updated it..

Comment: see my update question , we found bug in the syntax

Comment: @yael : bug is not in syntax, you changed the file delimiter itself. Your original file had = as delimiter, now it is just space. hence the solution needs to be modified. Updating it

Comment: ( +1 ) for your effort